# Winforms IoC Container - How to handle concrete types with a presenter factory

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, simple-injector

**Background**

I'm using Winforms with a MVP pattern to create an application. I'm using SimpleInjector as my IoC container. My presenters inherit from:

```
public interface IPresenter<TView>
{
    TView View { get; set; }
}

internal class HomePresenter : IPresenter<IHomeView>
{
    public IHomeView View { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

In order to create my presenters, I have decided to use a presenter factory with the following method:

```
public static IPresenter<TView> CreateForView<TView>(TView view)
    {
        var presenter = _container.GetInstance<IPresenter<TView>>();
        presenter.View = view;
        return presenter;
    }
```

And then in each view, the view creates its own presenter by calling the presenter factory:

```
_homeMainPresenter = (HomePresenter) presenterFactory.CreateForView<IHomeView>(this);
_homeMainPresenter.View = this;
```

In my Program.cs file, I have:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Bootstrap();

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run((HomeView)container.GetInstance<IHomeView>());
    }

    private static void Bootstrap()
    {
        // Create the container
        container = new Container();

        // Register types
        container.Register<IHomeView, HomeView>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<IPresenter<IHomeView>, HomePresenter>();
        ...

        // Verify the container
        container.Verify();
    }
```

**Problem**

When the presenter factory is called from the HomeView view, the type fed into the factory is a HomeView type, not IHomeView. So, the application throws an exception because the container does not have a HomeView registration (only IHomeView). My presenters all have interfaces for the views references they store as I feel this will be better for testing. How do I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a interface-to-implementation binding for your forms is not useful, since they are root types for your presentation technology. Most presentation technologies can't deal with custom abstractions anyway and this is the reason that you are casting your `IHomeView` back to `HomeView` to allow it to be passed on to the `Application.Run` method.

Instead of resolving the presenter from within the view, you can do the following instead:

```
public interface IHomeView { }

public interface IPresenter<TView> {
    TView View { get; set; }
}

public class HomeView : Form, IHomeView
{
    private readonly IPresenter<IHomeView> presenter;

    public HomeView(IPresenter<IHomeView> presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here the Form gets injected with an `IPresenter<IHomeView>` and stores that incoming dependency. The factory is not needed anymore and can be removed from your code.

And in your program main:

```
static void Main()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Bootstrap();

    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(GetForm<HomeView, IHomeView>(container));
}

private static void Bootstrap()
{
    // Create the container
    container = new Container();

    // Register types
    // NOTE: We register HomeView as concrete type; not by its interface.
    container.Register<HomeView>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    // Here we batch-register all presenters with one line of code and
    // since the forms depend on them, they need to be singletons as well.
    container.Register(typeof(IPresenter<>),  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), 
        Lifestyle.Singleton);
    ...

    // Verify the container
    container.Verify();
}

private static TForm GetForm<TForm, TView>() where TForm : Form, TView
{
    var form = container.GetInstance<TForm>();
    container.GetInstance<IPresenter<TView>>().View = form;
    return form;
}
```

The factory class is now replaced with the `GetForm` method that is part of the composition root; Forms don't have access to it. The generic types allow us to resolve the proper presenter, while keeping the code type-safe.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I appreciate your time. That all makes sense. This leads to another thing I've been debating for a while. My main view is quite complex, so I was thinking of splitting up my presenter into smaller presenters, with each one focused on a specific functional area. What are your thoughts there? That plan wouldn't exactly fit with your above strategy. I could instead create a bunch of partial class files, each one implementing a different functional area and perhaps a representative interface. i.e. `IHomeView` , `IHomeScheduleView`, etc. Then it would still be one presenter per view

Comment: Then again, if I had a different service for each functional area showing on the HomeView form, that would mean at least 6 services would need to be injected into the HomePresenter. That seems to scream SRP problems... but, I don't know how to avoid that. All those functional areas need to be on the MainView.

Comment: Alright, last question. Because the Presenter reference is stored in the View as `IPresenter<IHomeView>` and the View reference is stored in the Presenter as `IHomeView`, that makes it difficult to communicate between View and Presenter. Before, if a button were clicked on the view, I would just call `presenter.HandleButtonClick()` from the view. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: @Andrew Composing views out of smaller parts makes a lot of sense and in that case each 'child' view would have its own presenter. All views can bind to the same DTO/command message that is being sent when you press 'save' in the main view. Both presenters and views should not know about each others inplementations. I think normally it is the presenter who hooks itself to an event on the view abstraction.

Comment: I have successfully implemented this strategy. I'm running into an issue though. In the view interfaces, I have events defined that views implement, and then the presenters can subscribe to. Before this change, I subscribed the presenters to the events in the presenter constructors. With your new implementation, because the presenter is created first, and then injected into the view constructor, I can't subscribe the presenter to the View events in the presenter constructor because the view doesn't exist. Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: What about something like this in the view constructor @Steven: `this.presenter = presenter;  this.presenter.View = this;  this.presenter.SubscribeToViewEvents();`  I could add the `SubscribeToViewEvents()` method to `IPresenter<>`. Doesn't seem like a very elegant solution though.

Comment: @Andrew: You can let the presenter subscribe to the events of the view at the time you set the `View`; i.e. *inside* the `setter` of the `View` property. Or -since you probably never will call the `getter` of the `IPresenter<T>.View` property, change it to a method, like `SetView(T)`.